# How to get all property of child class in 'List' element in C#?

Tags: list, class, collections

I want to get all property in child class and all from base class when i add it into List<>.

[image: I can get only property of child class from List<>]]

My Child class "SellNumber.cs":

```
class SellNumber : Entity
{
    public SellNumber()
    {
        TableName = "tbl_sell_number";
        Record_status = (int)EStatusRecord.NEW;
        Buyer_number = new SecurityHelper().getCurrentIndexOfBuyer();
    }

    private long id_number;

    public long Id_number
    {
        get { return id_number; }
        set { id_number = value; }
    }   
    private int lottery_buy;

    public int Lottery_buy
    {
        get { return lottery_buy; }
        set { lottery_buy = value; }
    }
    private long price_buy_number;

    public long Price_buy_number
    {
        get { return price_buy_number; }
        set { price_buy_number = value; }
    }
    private long buyer_number;

    public long Buyer_number
    {
        get { return buyer_number; }
        set { buyer_number = value; }
    }

    private int channel_id;

    public int Channel_id
    {
        get { return channel_id; }
        set { channel_id = value; }
    }

    private int shift_id;

    public int Shift_id
    {
        get { return shift_id; }
        set { shift_id = value; }
    }

}
```

Base class

```
class Entity : BaseEntity
{

    public Entity()
    {
        User_create = new SecurityHelper().getCurrentUser();
        User_update = new SecurityHelper().getCurrentUser();
        Date_create = DateHelper.DATE_TO_DAY_DAYTIME;
        Date_update = DateHelper.DATE_TO_DAY_DAYTIME;

    }
    private long user_create;

    public long User_create
    {
        get { return user_create; }
        set { user_create =value; }
    }
    private long user_update;

    public long User_update
    {
        get { return user_update; }
        set { user_update = value; }
    }
    private String date_create;

    public String Date_create
    {
        get { return date_create; }
        set { date_create = value; }
    }
    private String date_update;

    public String Date_update
    {
        get { return date_update; }
        set { date_update = value; }
    }

    private int record_status;

    public int Record_status
    {
        get { return record_status; }
        set { record_status = value; }
    } 
}
```

**Edited:**

I want to get all property in child class and all from base class when i add it into List<>. I have class 'SellNumber.cs' which extends from class 'Entity.cs', so I want to use all properties of parent class to use with collection 'List'.